# Decrypting SSL/HTTPS with wireshark with private key of https server

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark, packet-capture

Say i have a client device and a https server. On the client device I'm sniffing all incoming and outgoing traffic and I would like to decrypt the traffic that is hitting my https server.

Can I supply wireshark with the https servers private key used for generating the ssl certificate in order to decrypt the traffic? If not, what options do I have for accomplishing this? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at https://mitmproxy.org/index.html

Comment: Yes I have used this, but I'm more interested in decrypting the traffic so i can use it with wireshark and it's analysis tools.